# Interpretation of coefficients in panel data

Tags: econometrics, interpretation, panel-data

A colleague asked me a question about the interpretation of coefficients in a panel data regression. I'm not familiar with this field but I want to help. The question is this:

> In our project, we estimated marginal models with unstructured covariance (which were specified similar to the example code above) in the SEM framework so that we can do a path analysis. We are unsure if the estimates (i.e., regression coefficients and path coefficients) should be interpreted as between-effects (i.e., they represent only cross-sectional information between respondents) or something similar to random-effects (i.e., a weighted average of between- and within-effects). In other words, should we consider the model shown in Ch. 7 in the book as a longitudinal model or a cross-sectional model?

The model in question is described in R code [here](https://content.sph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala2e/R_sect_7_6.html) and appears in Chapter 7.6 in the book "Applied Longitudinal Analysis" by Fitzmaurice et al. It's a model to investigate the effect of exercise therapy. Two groups of people are measured at times 2, 4, 6, 8 and 12. One group got exercise therapy and the other didn't.

Here is standalone R code for a slightly smaller version of the data set (the precise data doesn't really matter since the question is about interpreting the coefficients) with 4 people in each group.

```r
    dat <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
   2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
   1, 2, 2, 2, 2), time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), y = c(79, 83,
   81, 81, 80, 85, 77, 80, 79, 85, 82, 81, 82, 87, 80, 80, 80, 85, 82,
   82, 82, 86, 81, 81, 80, 86, 83, 82, 81, 86, 82, 81, 80, 87, 82, 81,
   81, 86, 82, 83), 
   newtime = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
   group.f = factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), 
   day.f = factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
   4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
   34, 35, 36, 37, 1, 2, 3, 4, 34, 35, 36, 37, 1, 2, 3, 4, 34, 35, 36,
   37, 1, 2, 3, 4, 34, 35, 36, 37, 1, 2, 3,   4, 34, 35, 36, 37)) 

library(nlme)
    
with(dat, model1 <<- gls(y ~ group.f*day.f, na.action=na.omit, 
                             corr=corSymm(, form= ~ newtime | id), 
                             weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | newtime)))
    summary(model1)

    Generalized least squares fit by REML
      Model: y ~ group.f * day.f 
      Data: NULL 
           AIC      BIC    logLik
      138.4992 173.5291 -44.24959
    
    Correlation Structure: General
     Formula: ~newtime | id 
     Parameter estimate(s):
     Correlation: 
      1     2     3     4    
    2 0.925                  
    3 0.916 0.990            
    4 0.810 0.938 0.958      
    5 0.762 0.839 0.881 0.931
    Variance function:
     Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
     Formula: ~1 | newtime 
     Parameter estimates:
            1         2         3         4         5 
    1.0000000 1.1207576 0.8518276 0.9337828 1.0240999 
    
    Coefficients:
                    Value Std.Error  t-value p-value
    (Intercept)     81.00 1.3070346 61.97235  0.0000
    group.f2        -0.50 1.8484260 -0.27050  0.7886
    day.f2           0.75 0.5590161  1.34164  0.1898
    day.f3           1.25 0.5303298  2.35702  0.0251
    day.f4           1.75 0.7839524  2.23228  0.0332
    day.f5           1.50 0.9128701  1.64317  0.1108
    group.f2:day.f2  1.00 0.7905682  1.26491  0.2156
    group.f2:day.f3  0.75 0.7499995  1.00000  0.3253
    group.f2:day.f4  0.25 1.1086761  0.22549  0.8231
    group.f2:day.f5  1.00 1.2909933  0.77460  0.4446
    
     Correlation: 
                    (Intr) grp.f2 day.f2 day.f3 day.f4 day.f5 g.2:.2 g.2:.3 g.2:.4
    group.f2        -0.707                                                        
    day.f2           0.086 -0.060                                                 
    day.f3          -0.541  0.383  0.738                                          
    day.f4          -0.407  0.288  0.737  0.927                                   
    day.f5          -0.314  0.222  0.490  0.732  0.844                            
    group.f2:day.f2 -0.060  0.086 -0.707 -0.522 -0.521 -0.346                     
    group.f2:day.f3  0.383 -0.541 -0.522 -0.707 -0.656 -0.517  0.738              
    group.f2:day.f4  0.288 -0.407 -0.521 -0.656 -0.707 -0.597  0.737  0.927       
    group.f2:day.f5  0.222 -0.314 -0.346 -0.517 -0.597 -0.707  0.490  0.732  0.844
    
    Standardized residuals:
           Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
    -1.3389087 -0.6736316 -0.1912727  0.2680863  1.7214541 
    
    Residual standard error: 2.614069 
    Degrees of freedom: 40 total; 30 residual
```

My answer is that I think this is a cross-sectional model, as there are no terms in the regression which apply to the individual subjects. The regression coefficients behave like the coefficients for `lm(y ~ group.f * day.f)`, but they are different because the model takes account of correlations between measurements. Also, random effects aren't introduced until the next chapter of the book.

However, I could be completely wrong, so I was hoping that there might be some experts here who can help.